# how to convert text in a table column to formula quickly

Tags: excel, vba

i have been looking around for a solution fo quite sometime for the following issue.

i have an excel workbook with an SQL database connected to it.
multiple columns in the sql database contains excel formulas

for example one formula is: "=HYPERLINK("MAILTO:example@example.com","example@example.com")"

but when i load the data into excel its seen as text and not as an formula.
so for a long time i have been looping thru the cells of each column with formulas and used the following code to convert the text to formula:

```
    dim cell as range

    With Blad2.ListObjects("example")
        for each cell in .ListColumns("Email").DataBodyRange
             cell.formula = cell.text
        next cell
    end with
```

but the code is getting slower overtime cause of the amount of data that gets put into
the sql database

after searching for sometime i still didn't find a proper solution until today

```
    dim Data as variant

    Data = Blad2.ListObjects("example").ListColumns("Email").DataBodyRange
    Blad2.ListObjects("example").ListColumns("Email").DataBodyRange.formula = Data
```

its way faster and gets the job done in matter of milliseconds instead of 5 to 10+ seconds

just wanted to leave it here in case somebody else has the same issue

Comment: What are the columns table format? If the columns format is General,  try to store the formulas in the SQL using a single quote before the equal sign and then after refreshing\loading the table in Excel, select the columns with the formulas and remove the single quote. I pretty sure that it will work.

Comment: in that way you would still need to loop thru the values to remove the single qoute.
causing the script to get slower.

Comment: There no need for a loop. You just need to  select the columns where you have the formulas and do a Find and Replace All. You search for '= and replace with =
Just record a macro and adapt to your needs.

Comment: if you use find it still needs to look in every single cell to check if it contains '= to replace it to =. in my case i just grab the data and paste it back